# Convolutional Layers Visualization in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to visualize the images in Convolutional Layers of a deep learning model, I found the code in the link.

https://github.com/yashk2810/Visualization-of-Convolutional-Layers/blob/master/Visualizing%20Filters%20Python3%20Theano%20Backend.ipynb

I applied the same code but I get empty images.

**I am using `flow_from_directory` to read the images.**

[image]

Please help me to find the solution..

The code here

```
 img_to_visualize = image.load_img('img.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))


    img_to_visualize = np.expand_dims(img_to_visualize,axis=0)

    def layer_to_visualize(layer):


        inputs = [K.learning_phase()] + vgg16_face_model.inputs

        _convout1_f = K.function(inputs, [layer.output])
        def convout1_f(X):
            # The [0] is to disable the training phase flag
            return _convout1_f([0] + [X])

        convolutions = convout1_f(img_to_visualize)
        convolutions = np.squeeze(convolutions)

        print ('Shape of conv:', convolutions.shape)

        n = convolutions.shape[0]
        n = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)))

        # Visualization of each filter of the layer
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
        for i in range(len(convolutions)):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(n,n,i+1)
            ax.imshow(convolutions[i], cmap='viridis')

    # Specify the layer to want to visualize
    layer_to_visualize(convout2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a "Shape of conv: (14, 14, 512)" output and you labeled your question "tensorflow", I would assume you are not using the Theano backend and has ["image_data_format" being "channels_last"](https://keras.io/backend/#image_data_format). I haven't used Theano myself but based on my search Thenao backend may have "channels_first" by default. Therefore, when looping through the layer output:

```
for i in range(len(convolutions)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(n,n,i+1)
    ax.imshow(convolutions[i], cmap='viridis')
```

You were actually drawing 14 images each being 14x512, rather than 512 images each being 14x14 (which I assume is what you want).

An easy (meaning you can use the function you've already coded) fix is to set "image_data_format" "channels_first" by adding `K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')` to the top of your notebook/script. However, this fix may be in conflict with your other codes. In that case, you can rewrite your layer visualization function. Here is an example which works with https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def visualize_layer(model, layer, input, train_mode=False):
    get_layer_output = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()],
                                  [layer.output])
    layer_output = get_layer_output([input, int(train_mode)])[0]
    print('Shape of {} layer output: {}'.format(layer, layer_output.shape))
    for i, sample in enumerate(layer_output):
        n_img = sample.shape[-1]
        img_row = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n_img)))
        fig = plt.figure()
        for j in range(n_img):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(img_row, img_row, j+1)
            ax.imshow(sample[:, :, j], cmap='gray')
        fig.savefig('sample_{}.png'.format(i))

visualize_layer(model, model.layers[1], [x_train[0]])
```